# Looking for T4 CSLA Code Generator

Tags: vb.net, csla

I am looking for T4 Code Generator for CSLA. It must work with VS2012.

There is one version on CodePlex which I am using for 2010 but the 2012 version is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the code generators I am aware of:

http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/codegen.aspx